# Keeping a DIV at static Height, But the one above it at Dynamic Height

Tags: html, css

```css
.getsmaller {
    display: block;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 150px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='getsmaller'></div>
<div class='additions'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

In this `HTML` Structure here, How can i make the `height` gets smaller depending on the `.additions`?

For example, As it is written in the first example, It is in a one line, Now what i want to happen when it is more than one line is to make `.getsmaller` height becomes smaller and move the `.addition` higher, Something like this.

```css
.getsmaller {
    display: block;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 120px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='getsmaller'></div>
<div class='additions'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

To clear it a litte, I want to keep the `.addition` in its place And make it get Higher only, Not to move down. But only change the height of `.getsmaller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex like this:

```css
body { /* I used the body as the main container but it can be any other element*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.getsmaller {
  flex: 1; /* this will make the div take the remaining spaces so it will get smaller when the cotnent of the other grow*/
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='getsmaller'></div>
<div class='additions'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

Comment: Setting a `min-height` would make it stop at that `height`, correct? Can i use this with Bootstrap Classes?

Comment: @Toleo yes sure you can set min-height and also use bootstrap with this ;) simply pay attention to the property ... have a try and you can get back to me if you have trouble

Comment: After many tries, I guess there is no way to mimic this using Bootstrap Grids.

Comment: @Toleo it's the V3 of bootstrap ? and am sure we can, we simply need to setup correctly the CSS

Comment: Is it possible to get it working If i removed `height: 100vh;` and added inside `.getsmaller` a text to make it `overflow:scroll`?